# Unable to change UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

**Background** When my app loads a `UINavigationController` is programmatically added and given a `leftBarButtonItem` and a `rightBarButtonItem`.  During launch a check is made to see if new data is required and if so a method is run to go and get new data from our web server.  During this time, the `rightBarButtonItem` is changed to a `UIActivityIndicatorView` which will show a spinning activity indicator.  When the data download is done, the `rightBarButtonItem` returns to a `UIBarButtonItem`.  This works fine.

On another `UIViewController` I need to allow the user to manually get new data and send their data to us.  During this time I need the rightBarButtonItem to change to a `UIActivityIndicatorView` as before.  But when I try to do so, the data is downloaded ok but the `rightBarButtonItem` is never changed.

I think my problem may have something to do with me not being able to reference the `UINavigationController` and its navigationItems.

**Code** My first `UIViewController's` implementation where the rightBarButtonItem is changed:

```
-(void)statusIsLoading{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *uiLoading = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    uiLoading.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    NSLog(@"Start animating");
    [uiLoading startAnimating];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:uiLoading];   
}
-(void)statusFinishedLoading{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *uiLoading = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    uiLoading.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [uiLoading stopAnimating];

    UIBarButtonItem *showSettingsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Settings.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showSettings:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = showSettingsButton;
}
```

**What I have tried** I have tried setting the `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` in the second `UIViewController` but this does nothing.  I have also tried running the method that calls the above two methods from an instantiated class:

```
    InitViewController *ivcInstance = [[InitViewController alloc] init];
    [ivcInstance performUpdate];
```

This runs the 'performUpdate' code just fine, the 'performUpdate' method called the 'statusIsLoading' and 'statusFinishedLoading' methods but the `rightBarButtonItem` does not change.

I think there is something very simple I am missing here.  Thanks.

**Edit** I have just tried checking for the current value of the rightBarButtonItem on the pageLoad of the second UIViewController and it appears to be nil:

```
UIBarButtonItem *newItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
```

Here newItem = nil.  Am I not targeting the correct navigationItem? should it be something other than 'self'?

**Edit 2**

In the second UIViewController I can alter the properties of the navigationBar:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:0.01 blue:0.36 alpha:2.0f]];
```

But if I try the same with the barButtonItem then nothing happens, why is this?

```
[self.navigationController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:uiLoading]];
```

same with:

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:uiLoading]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `statusFinishedLoading` you have some unused codes like below

```
-(void)statusFinishedLoading
{
    /*UIActivityIndicatorView *uiLoading = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    uiLoading.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [uiLoading stopAnimating];*/ //These are unused codes.

    UIBarButtonItem *showSettingsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Settings.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showSettings:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = showSettingsButton;
}
```

Also put `NSLog` in `statusFinishedLoading` methods and check whether this method called or not.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, that code is actually needed to stop the animation of the UIActivityIndicatorView - ([uiLoading stopAnimating];).  I could probably declare the indicator outside of those methods. I have stepped through the code and statusFinishedLoading does fire with no exceptions or errors.

Comment: have you set self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil; and check whether the old bar button removed or not.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that in second UIViewController and it does not remove the rightBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the **rightBarButtonItem** within a main-thread block. Once you have received the response, it should not block the UI.

```
-(void)statusFinishedLoading
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *uiLoading = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    uiLoading.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [uiLoading stopAnimating];

    UIBarButtonItem *showSettingsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Settings.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showSettings:)];

    //Use a block to set the rightBarButton.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = showSettingsButton;
    });
}
```

Hope this does the trick.

Edit : You need to create a UINavgationitem in the storyboard, connect the outlet to the .h file and call it **statusNavigationItem** then reference this navigationItem object to set the rightBarButton.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just tried your idea (and variations of it like putting this call on the UIViewController in question rather than the UIVC where those methods reside.  Still no joy.  I just noticed that self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil when I check for it in the second VC.

Comment: In that case, create a UINavigationItem object on the viewController and connect the outlets accordingly.

Comment: That kind of makes sense, I am an obj-c noob though - what would I need to do?

Comment: My UINavigationController is added programmatically when the app loads.  In the story board, none of my UIVC have a navigation controller, does that matter?  Will adding one in the story board affect the, already present, nav controller?

Comment: Try to access the navigationItem correctly as <UINavigationController>.navigationItem...self.navigationItem would not have a reference everywhere.